# How to reduce recursive variadic inheritance code bloat?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

Let's say I want to create a variadic interface with different overloads for the structs A,B,C:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

template <typename ... Ts>
class Base;

template <typename T>
class Base<T>{
  public:
    virtual void visit(const T& t) const
    {
      // default implementation
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
class Base<T, Ts...>: Base<T>, Base<Ts...>{
public:
  using Base<T>::visit;
  using Base<Ts...>::visit;   
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    auto base = Base<A,B,C>{};
    auto base2 = Base<A,C,B>{};
    base.visit(a);
    base2.visit(b);
}
```

Now funtionally `Base<A,B,C>` is identical to `Base<A,C,B>` but the compiler still generates the different combinations. Of course with more template parameters it gets worse.

I assume there is some meta programming magic which can cut this code bloat down.
One solution might be to define `template<typename T, typename U> Base<T,U>` in a way that it checks if `Base<U,T>` already exists. This could reduce at least some combinations and can probably be done by hand for triplets as well. But I am missing some meta programming magic and hoping for a more general approach.

**Edit:**
I would like to have the variadic Interface for a (simplified) use case like that:

```
class Implementation:public Base<A,B,C>
{
  public:
       void visit(const A& a) const
       {
           std::cout <<"Special implementation for type A";
       }

       void visit(const B& a) const
       {
           std::cout <<"Special implementation for type B";
       }

       // Fall back to all other types.
};

using BaseInterface = Base<A,B,C>;
void do_visit(const BaseInterface& v)
{
    v.visit(A{});
    v.visit(B{});
    v.visit(C{});
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BaseInterface> v= std::make_unique<Implementation>();
    do_visit(*v);
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is that there could be potentially a lot of types A,B,C,... and I want to avoid code duplication to define the overload for each type.

Comment: Looks like member function should be a template not a class. Please provide more details so it is clear what are the constraints.

Comment: GCC with -O2 basically generates no assembly code for your snippet

Comment: I'm almost certain you need a way to strictly order your structs so that you can sort them at compile time. Then you just always sort the parameters of `Base` and won't have duplicates.

Comment: `Base<A,B,C>`  might be functionally identical to `Base<A,C,B>` in your case. Just be aware it isn't necessarily so in every case.

Comment: why can't you have `template <typename Visitor> void do_visit(const Visitor& v);`? I guess that the only reason you want a `virtual` method is to have a non-template base. But do you actually need a non-template base interface?

Comment: Your last snippet won't work because you don't inherit from `BaseInterface`. Please include the definition of the later and explain where is it in the hierarchy.

Comment: @YakovGalka: thanks for the hint. I forgot a typedef, which I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base<A, B, C>` instantiates `Base<A>`, `Base<B, C>`, `Base<B>`, `Base<C>`
and
`Base<A, C, B>` instantiates `Base<A>`, `Base<C, B>`, `Base<B>`, `Base<C>`

Whereas final nodes are needed, intermediate nodes increase the bloat.

You can mitigate that issue with:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseLeaf
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseLeaf() = default;
    virtual void visit(const T& t) const
    {
      // default implementation
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
class Base : public BaseLeaf<Ts>...
{
public:
    using BaseLeaf<Ts>::visit...;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nzo9fYE1r)

`Base<A,B,C>` and `Base<A,C,B>` are still different types.

To be able to have same type, they should alias to the same type, and for that, ordering `Ts...` should be done in a way or another.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't compile with the example, as the call to visit is ambigious.

Comment: @S.Li: Once typo fixed, it compiles fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nzo9fYE1r) (Demo added).

Comment: I think this needs to be combined with my order enforcing strategy.  You're still instantiating `Base<A,C,B>` which according to OP's specs is redundant.

Comment: @Spencer: as `static_assert(std::ranges::is_sorted(std::array{ visit_sequence_v<Ts>...});` :-)

Comment: @Spencer: answers are complementary. I was looking for a link for sorting types on SO, but checking order is simpler :-)

Comment: Your answer made me curious, so I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044728/does-the-c-empty-base-or-possibly-some-other-optimization-apply-to-classes-t).

Comment: I like your solution, as it is cleaner than mine anyways. It doesn't completely solve the problem but at least reduces some of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the member function should be a template rather than the class.

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

class Foo {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    void visit(const T& t) const
    {
      // default implementation
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    auto foo = Foo{};
    foo.visit(a);
    foo.visit(b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nTrYY6qcn

I'm not sure what is your aim, since there is not enough details. With current information I think this is best solution (there is a also a lambda which [can address issue too](https://godbolt.org/z/18jhhGfTK)).

Comment: The thing is, `visit` is `virtual` in OP's code.

Comment: Yes, but there is no explanation why. Its just dangling. If his example shows some use of polymorphism then it would be clear if it is needed or not (since there is better solution). In current version name resolution does nice job.

Comment: As Spencer said: I want a virtual function, thus I can not easily template it. I extended the use case to better illustrate the point

Comment: @S.Li please update a question to explain why virtual is needed. Best approach is provide a test which should pass.

Comment: @MarekR: I updated the question, to show the need of a polymoprhic interface

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to enforce some sort of discipline on the order of template parameters.  You can do this with a template variable and a few `static_assert`s:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts>
class Base;

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
};

struct C
{
};

struct D
{
};

template <class T>
static constexpr int visit_sequence_v = -1;

template <>
constexpr int visit_sequence_v<A> = 0;

template <>
constexpr int visit_sequence_v<B> = 1;

template <>
constexpr int visit_sequence_v<C> = 2;

template <typename T>
class Base<T>{
  public:
    static_assert(visit_sequence_v<T> >= 0, "specialize visit_sequence_v for this type");
    virtual void visit(const T& t) const 
    { 
       // do nothing by default
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Base<T1, T2>: Base<T1>, Base<T2>
{
public:
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<T1, T2> || visit_sequence_v<T1> < visit_sequence_v<T2>);
  using Base<T1>::visit;
  using Base<T2>::visit;   
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Ts>
class Base<T1, T2, Ts...>: Base<T1>, Base<T2, Ts...>
{
public:
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<T1, T2> || visit_sequence_v<T1> < visit_sequence_v<T2>);
  using Base<T1>::visit;
  using Base<Ts...>::visit;   
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    auto base = Base<A,B,C>{};
    //auto base2 = Base<A,C,B>{}; // static_assert fails 
    //auto base3 = Base<A,B,C,D>{}; // forgot to specialize
    base.visit(a);
}
```

Notice the point here is to cause a compilation failure if you get the order wrong.  If someone has the chops to do a compile-time sort it may be possible to cobble up a traits class (or a template function that you can use `decltype` on the return type) that selects an implementation of `Base` in the correct order.

One alternative is to declare a full specialization of `Base` for every individual type that can be visited (supplying a "default implementation" for `visit`) and declare a `static constexpr visit_sequence` within each specialzation.

A problem inherent in your method is that in the case of multiple inheritance, `visit` can be ambiguous:

```
struct E: public A, public B
{
};

// 5 MiNuTES LATeR...

DescendantOfBase<A, B> a_b;
E e;
a_b.visit (e); // ambiguous
```

Comment: This is a possible solution, but not perfect, as we need to add for each type visit_sequence. 
If I want to provide only the boilerplate and let only the user do the specialization, this might be a bit of a problem.
But a template using E should work and not be ambiguous?
`DescendantOfBase<E> visitorE; E e; visitorE.visit (e); // should work?`

Comment: @S.Li You're correct on both counts. Unfortunately, even if something like `type_info::hash_code` were made constexpr the values would differ from translation unit to translation unit.  And yes, including `E` in the sequence should resolve the ambiguity.