# Does the C++ empty-base (or possibly some other) optimization apply to classes that are instantiated by a descendant but not declared as a variable?

Tags: c++, optimization

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042810/how-to-reduce-recursive-variadic-inheritance-code-bloat/74043589?noredirect=1#comment130737343_74043589) illustrates how a variadic template that descends from shorter versions of itself instantiates all of the variadic tail-sequence specializations in the chain. For example, given:

```
template <class...Ts>
class templ;

template <class T>
class templ<T>
{
    virtual void foo() = 0; // OP of the other question wanted virtual
};


template <class F, class...R>
class templ: public templ<F>, templ<R...>
{
    using templ<F>::foo;
    using templ<R...>::foo;
};
```

`templ<A, B, C, D>` will instantiate `templ<A>`, `templ<B>`, `templ<C>`, `templ<D>`, `templ<B, C, D>`, and `templ<C, D>`.   Once of the answers suggested the introduction of code bloat by the instantiation of `templ<B, C, D>`, and `templ<C, D>`, which only exist in the inheritance chain.  But it occurred to me that a C++ optimizer should be able to avoid generating code for at least those two instantiations, since they do nothing.  In this case, the optimizer would elide  `templ<B, C, D>`, and `templ<C, D>` subobjects and vtable sections in `templ<A, B, C, D>`, if no objects of those other types are declared or instantiated in an expression. Can an optimizer do that?

(This may even work for the `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` specializations...`templ<A, B, C, D>` would be laid out like a similar class with no base classes, and a single vtable with four entries).

In a guess at the answer, this seems like a consequence of the empty base class optimization.  Is it?

Comment: But a class with virtual members isn't empty! There's the reference/pointer to the v-table as a hidden member. That's why the size of a virtual class is larger than the sum of the sizes of the members even if you can guarantee no padding bytes being inserted.

Comment: @Aconcagua  The empty-base optimization was just a guess (and possibly just a starting point).  Those two intermediate classes, at least, contribute nothing to the vtable. Can the optimizer 'skip' them or fold them into the 'used' class?

Comment: My initial point was mainly the number of instantiations and the need of recursion, versus one variadic expansion.

Comment: @Jarod42  OK, but my mind tends to wander...

Comment: Well, there are two base classes involved – *each* of comes with its own v-table. Note that these base classes might be *specialised*, one of or both coming with a concrete implementation (in the latter case your `using` expressions are ambigous). If just one, the resulting v-table of the derived class will contain a pointer to this single implementation – or an own one, differing from the base class' one, if some specialisation provides such one.

Comment: @Aconcagua  Ideally, the optimizer would know that (there would be some internal 'overrides_any_virtual_functions' attribute). However, if you want to post all this as an answer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Just re-thinking if a compiler might indeed condense or skip a v-table. There's yet another problem, though: What if you cast a derived template to a base one? If the v-table had been skipped one would have to use the one of the derived class. This is, though, only possible if the layout is identical – or at least the one of the base is a prefix of the one of the derived. *Fully specialised* the compiler indeed would know...

Comment: Should be kept in mind that v-tables are **not** part of the C++ standard – they are nothing more than the *de-facto* standard how polymorphism is implemented (even across different languages supporting it). So actually a compiler can do *anything* with as long as the behaviour of virtual functions remains conform to what the standard defines!